# When using FCM, how to let my server know that the FCM service on the device is shutdown

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am planning top use FCM with my react-native iOS / Android App. And I need to let my backend know that the user (or OS) kill the application, i.e that FCM won't be able to activate the application upon receiving a notification. In the FCM documentation it is said that FCM will be shutdown.

I could not find a way to get a graceful AppState (or something else) notification of the impeding shutdown.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry, FCM will restart your application when user clicks on the notification in case of notification messages, or directly start your app's service on data messages. Check the FCM manual - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive